# How do I ask for notifications permission in an IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, notifications, apple-push-notifications

In my on-boarding I have a `UIPageViewController` containing a ‘primer’ screen at the end for authorizing notifications. The user would tap a button labeled “Enable Notifications” and the notifications permission dialog would appear. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put:

**Objective-C**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                      }];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; // you can also set here for local notification.
```

**Swift**

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() // you can also set here for local notification.
```

inside your `IBAction`.

Please remember also add `import UserNotifications` for **Swift** or `#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>` for **Objective-C** in file where you have `IBAction` and make sure that `Push Notification` is activated under `target` - `Capabilities` - `Push notification`.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

Comment: `UIUserNotificationSettings` is deprecated in iOS 10. You should Use `UNNotificationSettings` instead. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiusernotificationsettings